# django static files do not work for one application only

Tags: django, path, settings, django-staticfiles

My django application works well except for one application, all the static files are not loaded.

That happens on this url: `http://localhost/db_mgmt/add/dg/`. The template is loaded, but no css, no js.
When I look at one of the errors, the browser tries to load the page `http://localhost/db_mgmt/add/static/jquery.min.js` but the link should be: `http://localhost/static/jquery.min.js`
These files are loaded in base.html and work everywhere else...

Example of inclusion in base.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is my settings.py if it helps:

```
# Django settings for europolix project.
from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS as TCP

import os
#root of the project
PROJECT_ROOT=os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir))
#root of templates
TEMPLATE_ROOT=os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates')
#root of media files (import / export files)
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')
#root of static files (css, js, jquery...)
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
#WEB_ROOT=url of WSGIScriptAlias given in the apache configuration file (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf in Lubuntu 13.04)
#example: WSGIScriptAlias /europolix /var/www/europolix/europolix/wsgi.py -> WEB_ROOT="/europolix"
#in the apache configuration file, you must update the alias for static files as well
#ex: Alias /europolix/static /var/www/europolix/static -> WEB_ROOT="/europolix"
WEB_ROOT="/europolix"
#local
WEB_ROOT=".."
# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.actrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL=WEB_ROOT+'/media/'

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.actrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL=WEB_ROOT+'/static/'

# Additional locations of static files

STATICFILES_DIRS=(
    STATIC_ROOT,
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS=(
    TEMPLATE_ROOT
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)
```

If I print those variables in my view I have the following paths:

```
PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/europolix
STATIC_ROOT /var/www/europolix/static
STATIC_URL ../static/
WEB_ROOT ..
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

### Edit :

The variable WEB_ROOT is relative in local. Could it be the problem?
The variable searches in the parent directory (am I right?). So the applications with only one "child" in the url work (`http://localhost/act` or `http://localhost/export`) but not the applications with many "children" (e.g.: the one above, `http://localhost/db_mgmt/add/dg/`)

urls.py of the export app:

```
urlpatterns=patterns('export.views',
    url(r'^/?$', 'export', name='export'),
)
```

urls.py of the db_mgmt app that does not work well:

```
urlpatterns=patterns('db_mgmt.views',
    url(r'^add/(?P<field>\w+)/$', 'add', name='add'),
    url(r'^form_add.html/(?P<field>\w+)/$', 'form_add', name='form_add'),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought, the problem, one of the problems was about the WEB_ROOT variable. 
Here is how I fixed it:

```
WEB_ROOT="http://127.0.0.1:8000"
```

Another problem was the path of the template of my application db_mgmt:

```
url="/db_mgmt/form_add.html/"+field+"/"
```

I had to remove the first slash to have it work:

```
url="db_mgmt/form_add.html/"+field+"/"
```

Solved :).

Answer (score 0):

We would need to know more about the differences between the applications that work and the application that is giving you trouble